# Thread is killed in python flask/uwsgi/nginx post request - correct timeout settings?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm currently running a python flask application with uwsgi and nginx. The problem is that a thread is killed which is created in a flask post request after ~30 minutes. This can be observed regularly running the same post request. I've already set some uwsgi parameters in uwsgi.ini:

```
harakiri = 3600s
read_timeout = 3600s
socket_timeout = 3600s
http-timeout = 3600
```

But the request is always killed before finishing. Is there a parameter setting missing for this scenario?

Thank you in advance,

Andreas Schaefer.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I have an eerie similar problem with a similar setup. Even though I want to allow req to go up to 60 mins, request is always terminated at 30 mins